MAX1415 ADC not reading voltages correctly. Incorrect setup procedure?
My device uses two of the MAX1415 dual-channel sigma-delta ADCs. I've labeled them "MADC" and "CADC" for "Measurement ADC" and "Calibration ADC". They are supplied with an external 1.25V reference.
On the device there are also two DACs on the SPI line labeled "DDAC" and "GDAC" they supply some voltage which is present on the ADC pins. Right now that is around 0.5V. Overall, there is a total of 4 ICs on the SPI bus. Every second I take readings from both MADC and CADC.

Despite there being voltage on the ADC pins for all channels for both ADCs, which I have checked with a multimeter, I'm getting no readings and garbage readings for CADC ch2. I'm wondering if I have setup the ADC incorrectly or I'm missing something?
I'm using the following setup configs:
Communication Register

0b00100000 to indicate a write to the clock register
0b00010000 to indicate a write to the setup register

Clock Register (0b00110001)

First two bits are reserved (2 bits)
Internal clock enabled (1 bit)
Disabled clock output on pin 3 (1 bit)
No clock divisor (1 bit)
1MHz clock frequency (1 bit)
Default filter of 25Hz first notch and 6.55Hz -3dB cutoff (2 bits)

Setup Register (0b01000100)

Select self-calibration (2 bits)

PGA gain of 1 (3 bits)

Unipolar mode (1 bit)

Disabled input buffer (1 bit)

Calibration start (FSYNC) (1 bit)


Upon startup, I set the ~RESET pins high to enable them. Then I send the setup sequence to MADC and CADC as seen in the following two images. The correct sequence of bits ends up on the line and each respective ~CS goes low correctly.


After about 365ms, DRDY goes low for both which from my understanding indicates calibration is complete and I can start reading conversion from the data register. I poll ~DRDY to make sure it is low before reading.
I write one of the following two commands before reading 16 bits:

Read data reg for channel 1 (0b00111000)
Read data reg for channel 2 (0b00111010)

The entire SPI bus and relevant GPIO for the periodic reading can be seen in the following image.

Here are the relevant functions for setup and reading.
static void adc_register_setup(void)
{
    static uint8_t tx_buffer_init[4];
    const struct spi_buf tx_buf_init = {
        .buf = tx_buffer_init,
        .len = sizeof(tx_buffer_init)};
    const struct spi_buf_set tx_init = {
        .buffers = &tx_buf_init,
        .count = 1};
    tx_buffer_init[0] = WRITE_CLK_REG;
    tx_buffer_init[1] = CLK_REG_INIT;
    tx_buffer_init[2] = WRITE_SETUP_REG;
    tx_buffer_init[3] = SETUP_REG_INIT_CALIBRATION;

    spi_write_dt(&madc_spi_spec, &tx_init);
    spi_write_dt(&cadc_spi_spec, &tx_init);
}

static uint16_t adc_data_read(enum adc_type adc, uint8_t channel)
{

    /* Wait for data to be ready before reading */
    if (adc == MADC)
    {
        while (!gpio_pin_get_dt(&madc_drdy))
        {
        };
    }
    else if (adc == CADC)
    {
        while (!gpio_pin_get_dt(&cadc_drdy))
        {
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }

    static uint8_t tx_buffer[1];
    const struct spi_buf tx_buf = {
        .buf = tx_buffer,
        .len = sizeof(tx_buffer)};
    const struct spi_buf_set tx = {
        .buffers = &tx_buf,
        .count = 1};
    if (channel == 1)
    {
        tx_buffer[0] = READ_DATA_CH1;
    }
    else if (channel == 2)
    {
        tx_buffer[0] = READ_DATA_CH2;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }

    static uint8_t rx_buffer[2];
    struct spi_buf rx_buf = {
        .buf = rx_buffer,
        .len = sizeof(rx_buffer),
    };
    const struct spi_buf_set rx = {
        .buffers = &rx_buf,
        .count = 1};

    if (adc == CADC)
    {
        spi_write_dt(&cadc_spi_spec, &tx);
        spi_read_dt(&cadc_spi_spec, &rx);
    }
    else
    {
        spi_write_dt(&madc_spi_spec, &tx);
        spi_read_dt(&madc_spi_spec, &rx);
    }

    return (rx_buffer[0] << 8) | rx_buffer[1];
}

If anyone has ideas on what the issue could be I would greatly appreciate it.

I've resolved the issues. There was more than a multitude of things I was doing incorrectly. I'm posting my working code in the chance that anyone uses this device and is struggling as well.
#include <zephyr/kernel.h>
#include <zephyr/device.h>
#include <zephyr/devicetree.h>
#include <zephyr/drivers/gpio.h>
#include <zephyr/drivers/spi.h>
#include <zephyr/sys/printk.h>

#include "adc.h"

#define MEASUREMENT_ADC DT_NODELABEL(measurement_adc)
#define CALIBRATION_ADC DT_NODELABEL(calibration_adc)
#define SPIOP SPI_WORD_SET(8) | SPI_TRANSFER_MSB

enum adc_type
{
    MADC,
    CADC
};

struct spi_dt_spec madc_spi_spec = SPI_DT_SPEC_GET(MEASUREMENT_ADC, SPIOP, 0);
struct spi_dt_spec cadc_spi_spec = SPI_DT_SPEC_GET(CALIBRATION_ADC, SPIOP, 0);

static const struct gpio_dt_spec cadc_reset = GPIO_DT_SPEC_GET(CALIBRATION_ADC, reset_gpio);
static const struct gpio_dt_spec cadc_drdy = GPIO_DT_SPEC_GET(CALIBRATION_ADC, drdy_gpio);
static const struct gpio_dt_spec madc_reset = GPIO_DT_SPEC_GET(MEASUREMENT_ADC, reset_gpio);
static const struct gpio_dt_spec madc_drdy = GPIO_DT_SPEC_GET(MEASUREMENT_ADC, drdy_gpio);

static uint8_t MADC_active_channel;
static uint8_t CADC_active_channel;

static void adc_register_setup();
static bool adc_set_channel(enum adc_type adc, uint8_t channel);
static uint16_t adc_data_read(enum adc_type adc);

void adc_init()
{
    gpio_pin_configure_dt(&madc_reset, GPIO_OUTPUT);
    gpio_pin_configure_dt(&cadc_reset, GPIO_OUTPUT);
    gpio_pin_configure_dt(&madc_drdy, GPIO_INPUT);
    gpio_pin_configure_dt(&cadc_drdy, GPIO_INPUT);

    /* Enable ADCs */
    gpio_pin_set_dt(&cadc_reset, 0);
    gpio_pin_set_dt(&madc_reset, 0);

    adc_register_setup();
}

/* Call this function whenever switching the CADC channel to ensure accurate reads */
bool cadc_set_channel(uint8_t channel)
{
    return adc_set_channel(CADC, channel);
}

/* Call this function whenever switching the MADC channel to ensure accurate reads */
bool madc_set_channel(uint8_t channel)
{
    return adc_set_channel(MADC, channel);
}

/* Reads a single conversion from the active channel for MADC */
uint16_t madc_voltage_read()
{
    return adc_data_read(MADC);
}

/* Reads a single conversion from the active channel for CADC */
uint16_t cadc_voltage_read()
{
    return adc_data_read(CADC);
}

/* For debugging. Converts the voltage code to float. */
float adc_voltage_code_to_float(uint16_t read_code)
{
    return (1.25f / (65536)) * read_code;
}

/* Initializes clock, setup, and initiates self calibration for all channels */
static void adc_register_setup(void)
{
    /* CLK, and self-calibration for Ch1 */
    static uint8_t tx_buffer_init[4];
    const struct spi_buf tx_buf_init = {
        .buf = tx_buffer_init,
        .len = sizeof(tx_buffer_init)};
    const struct spi_buf_set tx_init = {
        .buffers = &tx_buf_init,
        .count = 1};
    tx_buffer_init[0] = WRITE_CLK_REG;
    tx_buffer_init[1] = CLK_REG_INIT;
    tx_buffer_init[2] = WRITE_SETUP_REG_CH1;
    tx_buffer_init[3] = SETUP_REG_INIT_CALIBRATION;

    /* Self-calibration for Ch2 */
    static uint8_t tx_buffer_ch2_cal[2];
    const struct spi_buf tx_buf_ch2_cal = {
        .buf = tx_buffer_ch2_cal,
        .len = sizeof(tx_buffer_ch2_cal)};
    const struct spi_buf_set tx_ch2_cal = {
        .buffers = &tx_buf_ch2_cal,
        .count = 1};
    tx_buffer_ch2_cal[0] = WRITE_SETUP_REG_CH2;
    tx_buffer_ch2_cal[1] = SETUP_REG_INIT_CALIBRATION;

    /* Calibrate MADC */
    spi_write_dt(&madc_spi_spec, &tx_init);
    while (!gpio_pin_get_dt(&madc_drdy))
    {
    };
    spi_write_dt(&madc_spi_spec, &tx_ch2_cal);
    while (!gpio_pin_get_dt(&madc_drdy))
    {
    };

    /* Calibrate CADC */
    spi_write_dt(&cadc_spi_spec, &tx_init);
    while (!gpio_pin_get_dt(&cadc_drdy))
    {
    };
    spi_write_dt(&cadc_spi_spec, &tx_ch2_cal);
    while (!gpio_pin_get_dt(&cadc_drdy))
    {
    };

    adc_set_channel(MADC, 1);
    adc_set_channel(CADC, 1);
}

/* Sets the active channel for the specified ADC. Must be called before reading to ensure valid conversions. */
static bool adc_set_channel(enum adc_type adc, uint8_t channel)
{
    if ((adc != MADC && adc != CADC) || (channel != 1 && channel != 2))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (adc == MADC)
    {
        MADC_active_channel = channel;
    }
    else if (adc == CADC)
    {
        CADC_active_channel = channel;
    }

    /* Throw away 5 conversions to let the ADC filter stabilize */
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        adc_data_read(adc);
    }

    return true;
}

/* Reads a single conversion from the active channel for the specified ADC */
static uint16_t adc_data_read(enum adc_type adc)
{
    if ((adc != MADC && adc != CADC))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    /* Write single command bit to tell communication register to read from data register */
    static uint8_t tx_buffer[1];
    const struct spi_buf tx_buf = {
        .buf = tx_buffer,
        .len = sizeof(tx_buffer)};
    const struct spi_buf_set tx = {
        .buffers = &tx_buf,
        .count = 1};

    /* Read 16 bit data register */
    static uint8_t rx_buffer[2];
    struct spi_buf rx_buf = {
        .buf = rx_buffer,
        .len = sizeof(rx_buffer),
    };
    const struct spi_buf_set rx = {
        .buffers = &rx_buf,
        .count = 1};

    /* Grab appropriate peripherals for ADC */
    uint8_t read_channel;
    struct spi_dt_spec *adc_spi_spec;
    const struct gpio_dt_spec *adc_drdy;
    if (adc == MADC)
    {
        read_channel = MADC_active_channel;
        adc_spi_spec = &madc_spi_spec;
        adc_drdy = &madc_drdy;
    }
    else if (adc == CADC)
    {
        read_channel = CADC_active_channel;
        adc_spi_spec = &cadc_spi_spec;
        adc_drdy = &cadc_drdy;
    }

    /* Set read command */
    if (read_channel == 1)
    {
        tx_buffer[0] = READ_DATA_CH1;
    }
    else if (read_channel == 2)
    {
        tx_buffer[0] = READ_DATA_CH2;
    }

    /* Write read command -> wait for ~DRDY -> read conversion */
    spi_write_dt(adc_spi_spec, &tx);
    while (!gpio_pin_get_dt(adc_drdy))
    {
    };
    spi_read_dt(adc_spi_spec, &rx);

    return (rx_buffer[0] << 8) | rx_buffer[1];
}

#ifndef ADC_H_
#define ADC_H_

#include <stdint.h>

/* Register commands for initialization sequence */
#define WRITE_CLK_REG (COMM_START << 7) | (CLOCK_REG_SEL << 4) | (WRITE << 3) | (POWER_ON << 2) | (CHANNEL1_SEL)                                      // 0b00100000
#define CLK_REG_INIT (ENABLE_INTCLK << 5) | (DISABLE_CLKOUT << 4) | (NORMAL_CLK_FREQ << 3) | (CLK_FREQ_2_4576MHZ << 2) | (FILTER_60HZ)                // 0b00110001
#define WRITE_SETUP_REG_CH1 (COMM_START << 7) | (SETUP_REG_SEL << 4) | (WRITE << 3) | (POWER_ON << 2) | (CHANNEL1_SEL)                                // 0b00010000
#define WRITE_SETUP_REG_CH2 (COMM_START << 7) | (SETUP_REG_SEL << 4) | (WRITE << 3) | (POWER_ON << 2) | (CHANNEL2_SEL)                                // 0b00010001
#define SETUP_REG_INIT_CALIBRATION (SELF_CALIBRATION << 6) | (PGA_GAIN_4 << 3) | (UNIPOLAR_MODE << 2) | (DISABLE_BUFFER << 1) | (FREE_RUN_CONVERSION) // 0b01010100

/* Read register commands */
#define READ_DATA_CH1 (COMM_START << 7) | (DATA_REG_SEL << 4) | (READ << 3) | (POWER_ON << 2) | (CHANNEL1_SEL)   // 0b00111000
#define READ_DATA_CH2 (COMM_START << 7) | (DATA_REG_SEL << 4) | (READ << 3) | (POWER_ON << 2) | (CHANNEL2_SEL)   // 0b00111010
#define READ_COMM_REG (COMM_START << 7) | (COMM_REG_SEL << 4) | (READ << 3) | (POWER_ON << 2) | (CHANNEL1_SEL)   // 0b00001000
#define READ_CLK_REG (COMM_START << 7) | (CLOCK_REG_SEL << 4) | (READ << 3) | (POWER_ON << 2) | (CHANNEL1_SEL)   // 0b00101000
#define READ_SETUP_REG (COMM_START << 7) | (SETUP_REG_SEL << 4) | (READ << 3) | (POWER_ON << 2) | (CHANNEL1_SEL) // 0b00011000

/* Communication register - 8 bits (read/write)
    communication-start/data-ready (1), register select (3), read/write select (1), power-down mode (1), channel select (2)
*/
/* communication-start/data-ready */
#define COMM_START 0

/* register selection */
#define COMM_REG_SEL 0b000
#define SETUP_REG_SEL 0b001
#define CLOCK_REG_SEL 0b010
#define DATA_REG_SEL 0b011
#define OFFSET_REG_SEL 0b110
#define GAIN_REG_SEL 0b111

/* read/write */
#define WRITE 0
#define READ 1

/* power-down mode */
#define POWER_ON 0
#define POWER_DOWN 1

/* channel select */
#define CHANNEL1_SEL 0b00
#define CHANNEL2_SEL 0b01

/* Setup register - 8 bits (read/write)
    mode control (2), PGA gain control (3), bipolar/unipolar mode (1), buffer enable (1), FSYNC: filter-synchronization/conversion-start (1)
*/
/* mode control*/
#define ADC_NORMAL_MODE 0b00
#define SELF_CALIBRATION 0b01
#define ZERO_SCALE_SYSTEM_CALIBRATION 0b10
#define FULL_SCALE_SYSTEM_CALBIRATION 0b11

/* PGA gain control */
#define PGA_GAIN_1 0b000
#define PGA_GAIN_2 0b001
#define PGA_GAIN_4 0b010
#define PGA_GAIN_8 0b011
#define PGA_GAIN_16 0b100
#define PGA_GAIN_32 0b101
#define PGA_GAIN_64 0b110
#define PGA_GAIN_128 0b111

/* bipolar/unipolar mode */
#define BIPOLAR_MODE 0
#define UNIPOLAR_MODE 1

/* buffer enable */
#define DISABLE_BUFFER 0
#define ENABLE_BUFFER 1

/* FSYNC */
#define FREE_RUN_CONVERSION 0
#define STOP_FREE_CONVERSION 1

/* Clock register - 8 bits (read/write)
    reserved (2), internal clock select (1), clock disable (1), clock divider control (1), clock frequency (1), filter selection (2)*/
/* internal clock select */
#define DISABLE_INTCLK 0
#define ENABLE_INTCLK 1

/* clock disable */
#define DISABLE_CLKOUT 1
#define ENABLE_CLKOUT 0

/* clock divider control */
#define NORMAL_CLK_FREQ 0
#define HALVE_CLK_FREQ 1

/* clock frequency */
#define CLK_FREQ_1MHZ 0
#define CLK_FREQ_2_4576MHZ 1

/* filter selection */
#define FILTER_25HZ 0b01 // For 1MHz fclkin, 6.55Hz -3dB cutoff
#define FILTER_60HZ 0b01 // For 2.4576MHz fclkin, 15.7Hz -3dB cutoff

void adc_init();
uint16_t madc_voltage_read();
uint16_t cadc_voltage_read();
bool madc_set_channel(uint8_t channel);
bool cadc_set_channel(uint8_t channel);

/* For debugging */
float adc_voltage_code_to_float(uint16_t read_code);

#endif /* ADC_H_ */
```

